# CSS grid creating extra gap

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've been creating a simple responsive CSS grid, but for some reason when I make the browser smaller it creates some extra space between the first and second columns. Here is my code.

```css
.services-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20rem, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(25rem, 1fr));
  justify-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  grid-column-gap: 5rem;
  grid-row-gap: 5rem;
}

.services-container div {
  background-color: #D00000;
  height: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="services-container">
  <div class="item-1">
    <h1>Услуга 1</h1>
    <p>Мини описание на услугата</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-2">
    <h1>Услуга 2</h1>
    <p>Мини описание на услугата</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-3">
    <h1>Услуга 3</h1>
    <p>Мини описание на услугата</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-4">
    <h1>Услуга 4</h1>
    <p>Мини описание на услугата</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-5">
    <h1>Услуга 5</h1>
    <p>Мини описание на услугата</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-6">
    <h1>Услуга 5</h1>
    <p>Мини описание на услугата</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change - grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20rem, 1fr));

```css
.services-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20rem, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20rem, 1fr));
  justify-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  grid-column-gap: 5rem;
  grid-row-gap: 5rem;
}

.services-container div {
  background-color: #D00000;
  height: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="services-container">
  <div class="item-1">
    <h1>Услуга 1</h1>
    <p>Мини описание на услугата</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-2">
    <h1>Услуга 2</h1>
    <p>Мини описание на услугата</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-3">
    <h1>Услуга 3</h1>
    <p>Мини описание на услугата</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-4">
    <h1>Услуга 4</h1>
    <p>Мини описание на услугата</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-5">
    <h1>Услуга 5</h1>
    <p>Мини описание на услугата</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-6">
    <h1>Услуга 5</h1>
    <p>Мини описание на услугата</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess that the cause of your *some extra spaces* is because of the minmax values in grid-template-columns or rows because the minmax will [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax#:%7E:text=The%20minmax()%20CSS%20function,is%20used%20with%20CSS%20Grids.) the size of your item when you change the browser size, sometimes it will be subtle if the min value is almost near to the size of max value.

I tried changing to both `20rem`:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20rem, 20rem));
```

and it just drops down when the screen is too small, no changes in gaps

It depends on the size of your minmax in grid-template